# $\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{E}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

My approach was to the following:

Let G be a domain, because of the Riemann mapping theorem $G$ is equivalent to the unit disc $\mathbb{E}$. With $z_0 \in G$ follows that $G\setminus \{z_0\}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}\setminus\{0\}$. 
Since $z_0$ was arbitrary $\bigcap_\limits{z_0\in[-1,1]}G\setminus \{z_0\}$ is equivalent to $\mathbb{E}\setminus\{0\}$.

I am now thinking about 'expanding' $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ but I'm not allowed to set $G=\mathbb{C}$ because then I can't use the Rieman mapping theorem. Is everything I did correct so far or is there another way of proving this?

Answer (score 1):

Consider first $U=\Bbb C_\infty\setminus[-1,1]$. By a Mobius transformation
we can map $U$ to the plane $V$ cut along the negative real axis. Taking
the square root and then another Mobius transformation takes $V$ to $D$,
the unit disc.

If we delete a point from $U$ we find that $U\setminus\{a\}$ is conformally
equivalent to $D\setminus\{b\}$ for some $b$. We can take $a=\infty$.
Whatever $b$ is, a further Mobius transformation takes $D$ to itself,
and $b$ to $0$.

Comment: thanks for your answer. unfortunately it didn't help me much cause we haven't dealt with mobius transformations in the course yet. but I still solved it by showing that the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+z^{-1})$ does everything I need and is biholomorphic.