# Show that $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ and $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ are conformally equivalent

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

So I have found this thread: [$\mathbb{C}\setminus[-1,1]$ is conformally equivalent to $\mathbb{E}\setminus\{0\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2824192/mathbbc-setminus-1-1-is-conformally-equivalent-to-mathbbe-setminus-0)

it says that the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$ from $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\}$ has the needed property to map these domains conformally to each other.
However I am stuck showing that, so I first need to show that

*) f(z) is injective and surjective, showing that its modulus is always $\leq 1$

*) calculating the inverse function:
for the inverse, what I have until now:

$ w = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{z^2+1}{z})$

$ 2wz = z^2+1$
however that would lead to a quadratic equation with the solution $w_{1,2} = z \pm \sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}$
I do not know whether that is right and how to proceed from here

**following the comments, I now know that the approach from the other thread can not lead to the solution, so I would be thankful if someone could help with another approach**

Comment: note that $|f(i/1000)|\ge 500-1/500 >1$ so your claim is incorrect

Comment: @Conrad: But if they are conformally equivalent, shouldn't the modulus of $f(z)$ be smaller than 1? Is the claim regarding modulus incorrect or the given function in general?

Comment: $f(z)=f(1/z)$ so the mapping is not injective.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: oh right, thank you, but is there any other way to show the conformal equivalence?

Comment: what about if you take $f: \mathbb{D}\setminus\{0\} \to \mathbb C, f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$; if $z=e^{i\theta}$ we get that $f(z)=\cos \theta$ so it has image precisely $[-1,1]$ while $0 \to \infty$; it is clearly injective inside the open unit disc since $f(z)=f(z_1)$ implies $z=z_1$ or $z=1/z_1$ and if $w$ is any complex number not in $[-1,1]$ the equation $f(z)=w$ (which is a quadratic) has a unique solution with $|z|<1, z \ne 0$ so is surjective too, hence $f$ works as the conformal mapping you want but in reverse, so $f^{-1}$ maps $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1] \to D^*$ conformally

Comment: @Conrad: thank you

Comment: happy to be of help